# dynamic heatmaps using plotly

Tags: plotly, heatmap

I have created a simple heatmap in plotly. below is the code:

Input data

```
var zValues = [
  [0.10, 0.30, 0.15, 0.25, 0.40],
  [0.20, 0.00, 0.75, 0.75, 0.00],
  [0.75, 0.75, 0.15, 0.65, 0.20],
  [0.50, 0.40, 0.00, 0.05, 0.10]
];

var data = [{
  x: xValues,
  y: yValues,
  z: zValues,
  type: 'heatmap',
  colorscale: colorscaleValue,
  showscale: true
}];

var layout = {
  title: 'Annotated Heatmap',
  annotations: [],
  xaxis: {
    ticks: '',
    side: 'bottom'
  },
  yaxis: {
    ticks: '',
    ticksuffix: ' ',
    width: 700,
    height: 700,
    autosize: false
  }
};

for ( var i = 0; i < yValues.length; i++ ) {
  for ( var j = 0; j < xValues.length; j++ ) {
    var currentValue = zValues[i][j];
    if (currentValue != 0.0) {
      var textColor = 'white';
    }else{
      var textColor = 'black';
    }
    var result = {
      xref: 'x1',
      yref: 'y1',
      x: xValues[j],
      y: yValues[i],
      text: zValues[i][j],
      font: {
        family: 'Arial',
        size: 12,
        color: 'rgb(50, 171, 96)'
      },
      showarrow: false,
      font: {
        color: textColor
      }
    };
    layout.annotations.push(result);
  }
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Now i want to update the data(zValues) after regular intervals(or reshuffle the data) so that the colors in the heatmap should keep on changing based on the new data values.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Plotly` stores the [data](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotdivdata-and-plotdivlayout) of your plot in the `data` attribute of the `div` where the plot is drawn. You can manipulate it and then call `Plotly.redraw`.

Alternatively you can use `Plotly.restyle`

```
Plotly.restyle(myDiv, 'z', [new_data]);
```

```js
var data = [{
  z: random_data(),
  x: [0, 1, 2],
  y: [0, 1, 2],
  type: 'heatmap'
}];

myDiv1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');
myDiv2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv1', data);
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv2', data);

function random_data() {
  new_z = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    new_z.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j += 1) {
      new_z[i].push(Math.random() * 100)
    }
  }
  return new_z
}

var interval1 = setInterval(function() {
  myDiv1.data.z = random_data();
  Plotly.redraw(myDiv1);
}, 1000);
var interval1 = setInterval(function() {
  Plotly.restyle(myDiv2, 'z', [random_data()]);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv1'></div>
<div id='myDiv2'></div>
```